# How can I check if a facebook user is offline (using offline_access to manage things)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like my app to handle certain things differently when the user is on or off facebook. Is there anyway to detect whether or not he is logged in (obviously my session will be valid because I have offline access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. API does not provide such information.